# ArgumentException was unhandled; Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, asp.net, emgucv, face-detection

I am trying to select and play a video file and detect face using "haar cascade". When i select a video file it shows exception "ArgumentException was unhandled" in this line
**int len = (int)memde.StreamLength;**
This is the code I used:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
                memde = new MediaDetClass();
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("temp");
                int len = (int)memde.StreamLength;
                label1.Text = "Length: " + len.ToString();
                trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                trackBar1.Maximum = len;
                trackBar1.Value = 0;
                counter = 0;
                Image img;
                memde.Filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                memde.CurrentStream = 0;
                float percent = 0.002f;
                Image<Gray, byte> gray;
                for (float i = 0.0f; i < len; i = i + (float)(percent * len))
                {
                    counter++;
                    string fbitname = storagepath + counter.ToString();
                    memde.WriteBitmapBits(i, 850, 480, fbitname + ".bmp");
                    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(fbitname);
                    img = Image.FromFile(fbitname + ".bmp");
                    img.Save(fbitname + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(i + fbitname + ".bmp");
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(new Bitmap(img));
                    gray = image.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                    MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
                 face,
                 1.2,
                 10,
                 Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                 new Size(20, 20));
                    foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
                    {
                        result = image.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                        image.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, as an alternative to your method the capture class of EMGUcv supports video files. Heres and example http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Video_Files Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell the MediaDetClass the file name, so the instance doesn't know it's length. So set the FileName property before getting the stream's length.

```
memde = new MediaDetClass();
memde.Filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
memde.CurrentStream = 0;
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("temp");
int len = (int)memde.StreamLength;
label1.Text = "Length: " + len.ToString();
trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
trackBar1.Maximum = len;
trackBar1.Value = 0;
counter = 0;
Image img;
float percent = 0.002f;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked..but now its showing another exception"Parameter is not valid" in the line  pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(fbitname); I want to show each frame in the picturebox. Please help!

Comment: where do you set the storagepath ?

Comment: i have declared it before button_click       namespace face
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string storagepath = @"temp\";
        static int counter = 0;
        Image<Gray, byte> result = null;
        HaarCascade face;
        MediaDetClass memde;

Comment: so fbitname is temp\1, doesn't look like a real bitmap name, which you are trying to assign. Try to debug your code and check the values of the variables

Comment: How can i show the frame in the picturebox..any idea?

Comment: try pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(fbitname + ".bmp");